# Symmetric space, octonionic structure and Lie triple system

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Consider the symmetric space $SO(6)/SO(2)\times SO(4)$. Its tangent space $\mathfrak{m}$ can be identified with the octonions (in the form of the Cayley-Dickson doubling) as a vector space. What is the relation between the octonionic multiplication on the vector space $\mathfrak{m}$ and the Lie triple product $[[X,Y],Z]$ on $\mathfrak{m}$?

Comment: It's not obvious to me how one gets an identification between the octonions and $\mathfrak{m}$ (which I guess is the tangent space at the class of the identity). Could you spell it out a little?

Comment: Such space is both Kahler and Quaternionic-Kahler depending on the factor of the isotropy group you are interested on (this in turns should depend on the identification with the octonions you had in mind). Now the Lie triple product you are asking about is just the curvature tensor $R(X,Y)Z$. In the Kahler case your space is the complex quadric and using Google you can find explicitly $R$ in terms of the complex structure. For the explicit form using the QK structure see Theorem 2, page 42, of Berndt's paper http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/55-1/19.pdf

Comment: @OliverNash , Yes $\mathfrak{m}$ is the tangent space and identified with two copied of quaternions  $\mathbb{H}^2$ or one copy of  octonions $\mathbb{O}$ as just vector space!. But essentially this tangent space structure of   Lie triple product. I thought this non associative structure will be identified with non associative structure of  alternative cross product on octonions. It seems I am wrong since Lie triple product  is not alternative.

Comment: @Holonomia, I should thank you very much for a nice and helpful reference. the expresseion of curvature tensor or that of Lie triple product in terms of the metric,  Hermitian and Quaternionic structure was so elegant.

Comment: @Ben McKay , Thank you for editing the text.